# Is it possible for a Form to Execute its button`s/commands without opening it?

Tags: vb.net

I'm creating a Payroll with 3, form 1 for Payroll and 2 for Payslip and 3 for attendance.

Now my Form 1 has a Get Attendance Button that will fill all textbox with the records from form 3 and calculate it. it also has a button to print the payslip that will open the form 2 and convert textbox values to label in form 2. and form 2 has a print button.

now i want to create a print all button that will print all attendance recorded in the database to payslip which i manage to do but i dont think it was efficient

here is my code:

```
        If txtempname.Items.Count = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("There is no Record to Print")
        Else
            bttnGetattendance.Visible = True
            For i = 0 To txtempname.Items.Count - 1
                txtempname.SelectedIndex = i
                bttnGetattendance.PerformClick()
                bttncalculate.PerformClick()
                printallnote()
                bttnPrint.Visible = True
                bttnPrint.PerformClick()
                PrintPayslip.printall()
                PrintPayslip.Close()
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
```

It did the purpose of print all, but all it did was automate what i would do when printing them manually, so the form open and close until it stop.

btw this is my print payslip code which

```
  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'PrintDocument1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = My.Settings.Printer
        'PrintDocument1.Print()
        PrintPreviewDialog1.Document = PrintDocument1
        PrintPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog()

    End Sub

    Public Sub printall()
        PrintDocument1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = My.Settings.Printer
        PrintDocument1.Print()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        AddPrinter.ShowDialog()
    End Sub

    Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage_1(sender As Object, e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
        Dim dm As New Bitmap(Me.Panel1.Width, Me.Panel1.Height)
        Panel1.DrawToBitmap(dm, New Rectangle(0, 0, Me.Panel1.Width, Me.Panel1.Height))
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(dm, 0, 0)

        Dim aPS As New PageSetupDialog
        aPS.Document = PrintDocument1
    End Sub

    Private Sub PrintPayslip_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Heading Placeholder Value get from Payroll
        Empname.Text = Payroll.txtempname.Text
        Empcode.Text = Payroll.txtempcode.Text
        Position.Text = Payroll.txtposition.Text
        Payperiodfrom.Text = Payroll.txtpayperiodfrom.Text

        'Earnings Placeholder Value get from Payroll
        h1.Text = Payroll.txtreghour.Text
        h2.Text = Payroll.txtovertime.Text
        h3.Text = Payroll.txtnightdiff.Text
        h4.Text = Payroll.txtsunday.Text
        h5.Text = Payroll.txtnonwork.Text
        h6.Text = Payroll.txtspecialholiday.Text
        lblsunot.Text = Payroll.txtsunot.Text

        'Earnings Amounts Placeholder Value get from Payroll
        amount1.Text = Payroll.txtreghouramount.Text
        amount2.Text = Payroll.txtovertimeamount.Text
        amount3.Text = Payroll.txtnightdiffamount.Text
        amount4.Text = Payroll.txtsundayamount.Text
        amount5.Text = Payroll.txtnonworkamount.Text
        amount6.Text = Payroll.txtspecialholidayamount.Text
        Totalearnings.Text = Payroll.txttotalearningamount.Text
        lblsunotamount.Text = Payroll.txtsunotamount.Text

        'Deduction Amounts Placeholder Value get from Payroll
        amounta1.Text = Payroll.txtsssamount.Text
        amounta2.Text = Payroll.txtphilamount.Text
        amounta3.Text = Payroll.txthdmfamount.Text
        amounta4.Text = Payroll.txtloanamount.Text
        Totaldeduc.Text = Payroll.txttotaldeduc.Text
        adddeduc1.Text = Payroll.txtadddeduc1.Text
        adddeduc2.Text = Payroll.txtadddeduc2.Text
        adddeduc3.Text = Payroll.txtadddeduc3.Text
        amounta5.Text = Payroll.txtdeduc1.Text
        amounta6.Text = Payroll.txtdeduc2.Text
        amounta7.Text = Payroll.txtdeduc3.Text


        'Loans Placeholder Value get from Payroll
        Actualoan.Text = Payroll.Loan_BalanceTextBox.Text
        Loanbalance.Text = Payroll.txtloanbalance.Text

        'Total Placeholder Value get from Payroll
        Grossearnings.Text = Payroll.txtgrossearnings.Text
        Grossdeduc.Text = Payroll.txtgrossdeduc.Text
        Netpay.Text = Payroll.txtnetpay.Text

        'Received & Date laceholder Value get from Payroll
        Receivedby.Text = Payroll.txtempname.Text
        Datereceived.Text = Today.Date
        lblNote.Text = Payroll.lblNote.Text



        'Duplicate Payslip

        'Heading Placeholder Value get from Payroll
        Empname1.Text = Payroll.txtempname.Text
        Empcode1.Text = Payroll.txtempcode.Text
        Position1.Text = Payroll.txtposition.Text
        Payperiodfrom1.Text = Payroll.txtpayperiodfrom.Text

        'Earnings Placeholder Value get from Payroll
        h11.Text = Payroll.txtreghour.Text
        h22.Text = Payroll.txtovertime.Text
        h33.Text = Payroll.txtnightdiff.Text
        h44.Text = Payroll.txtsunday.Text
        h55.Text = Payroll.txtnonwork.Text
        h66.Text = Payroll.txtspecialholiday.Text
        h77.Text = Payroll.txtsunot.Text

        'Earnings Amounts Placeholder Value get from Payroll
        amount11.Text = Payroll.txtreghouramount.Text
        amount22.Text = Payroll.txtovertimeamount.Text
        amount33.Text = Payroll.txtnightdiffamount.Text
        amount44.Text = Payroll.txtsundayamount.Text
        amount55.Text = Payroll.txtnonworkamount.Text
        amount66.Text = Payroll.txtspecialholidayamount.Text
        Totalearnings1.Text = Payroll.txttotalearningamount.Text
        amount77.Text = Payroll.txtsunotamount.Text

        'Deduction Amounts Placeholder Value get from Payroll
        amounta11.Text = Payroll.txtsssamount.Text
        amounta22.Text = Payroll.txtphilamount.Text
        amounta33.Text = Payroll.txthdmfamount.Text
        amounta44.Text = Payroll.txtloanamount.Text
        Totaldeduc1.Text = Payroll.txttotaldeduc.Text
        adddeduc11.Text = Payroll.txtadddeduc1.Text
        adddeduc22.Text = Payroll.txtadddeduc2.Text
        adddeduc33.Text = Payroll.txtadddeduc3.Text
        amounta55.Text = Payroll.txtdeduc1.Text
        amounta66.Text = Payroll.txtdeduc2.Text
        amounta77.Text = Payroll.txtdeduc3.Text



        'Loans Placeholder Value get from Payroll
        Actualoan1.Text = Payroll.Loan_BalanceTextBox.Text
        Loanbalance1.Text = Payroll.txtloanbalance.Text

        'Total Placeholder Value get from Payroll
        Grossearnings1.Text = Payroll.txtgrossearnings.Text
        Grossdeduc1.Text = Payroll.txtgrossdeduc.Text
        Netpay1.Text = Payroll.txtnetpay.Text

        'Received & Date laceholder Value get from Payroll
        Receivedby1.Text = Payroll.txtempname.Text
        Datereceived1.Text = Today.Date
        lblNote1.Text = Payroll.lblNote.Text
    End Sub
```

if possible i want a loading screen replace the opening and closing form 1 and form 2, until all payslip is print.

Comment: Yes, possible.  You would need to change the access modifier on the methods from private to public, then call the as per any other method.  I would suggest though, a better way to do this would be to move the code from your button click events (of course modified for any form objects, properties and fields) into a code module and call that from your button clicks

Comment: @Hursey Thank you it helps me a lot. I always thought that copying code from my button to another form is inefficient so I always just use the button.perform_click, didn't know that is more efficient.

Comment: @Hursey hello, i tried your suggestion about creating a module to write my for methods and then just call it there but i cant seem to make the print button work without showing the form for payslip. the code works because when i open the form all the information is correct and i can print it there but what i want is to print without opening said form. please help.

Comment: You might be better off posting a new question with the exact details of where you are at now and clear explanation of the roadblock(s)